# How to get item value of some name key in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I read object:

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
```

I have JSON like this:

```
     {"state": 
             [{"connected": true, "name": "smtp"}]
              {"connected": true, "name": "emailer"}
              {"connected": true, "name": "mysql"}
              {"connected": true, "name": "mongodb"}
              {"connected": true, "name": "redis"}
              {"state": 
                     [{"connected": true, "name": "mysql"}
                      {"connected": true, "name": "mongodb"}]
                       "connected": true, "name": "vault"}
```

What i should use to get connection status of item with any name? For example, "mysql" - "true".
Structure of JSON can be changed in future, that's why i don't want use code like this:

```
print data['state'][0]['connected']
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a recursive function to build a secondary table, in a manner such as:

```
def buildConnectionTable(table):
    result = {}

    if type[table] == list:
        subresult = buildConnectionTable(table[0])
        result.update(subresult)

    for key, value in table.items():
        if key == state:
            subresult = buildConnectionTable(value)
            result.update(subresult)
        else:
            result[value["name"]] = value["connected"]

    return result

connection_table = buildConnectionTable(data)

print connection_table["mysql"]
print connection_table["vault"]
print connection_table["redis"]
```

This is probably not correct code because I cannot test it at the moment, but hopefully it at least demonstrates a possible solution to the problem.